# Double Click for Publishers API in R

Tags: r, double-click

I am new to DFP so I would like to know whether there is an API which enables to export reports for queries built in DFP using R only?? I am not aware of other languages.

Kindly suggest or share any views if you know. I have searched but came across this one https://rdrr.io/github/StevenMMortimer/rdfp/f/README.md

Comment: How does rdfp not do what you want? Also, there are [client libraries for DFP](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/clients) written in Java and Python, among others, which you can run and process from within R, if you want, but you may just as well do all your data analysis in Python and forego R.

Comment: rdfp does not show as packages in library tried installing it

Comment: Did you try `devtools::install_github("ReportMort/rdfp")` as described in the readme file that you linked to? (You need to install devtools first.)

Comment: @user7843120  can you help with the python code